# debug openCV with qt creator on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: debugging, opencv, qt-creator, ubuntu-14.04

I try to debug some openCV code with qt creator on Ubuntu 14.04
But if i step through the lines the debugger don't step into the openCV files.

This is the code want to debug

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

Mat img_1 = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
Mat img_2;

FastFeatureDetector fast = FastFeatureDetector(); <-----

vector<KeyPoint> kp;

fast.detect(img_1,kp); <------

Scalar color = (255,0,0);

drawKeypoints(img_1,kp,img_2,color);

namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

imshow( "Display window", img_2 );

waitKey(0);

return -1;
}
```

I will step into the openCV files I comment with "<-----"

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you install OpenCV from *Ubuntu* repositories or did you build it from sources ?

Comment: I build it from sources with the DEBUG FLAG

Comment: sry that I ask again. Can anyone help me with my openCV-qtCreator-debugger problem? I completely remove openCV and reinstall it with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local but nothing happens. If I try the minimal example above I can step through the code but can't step into the openCV files.